# User Factory and Repository

Tags: .net, domain-driven-design, repository, factory

I'm in the process of determining an approach for design. I would like your inputs

I have 2 types of users

1. Corporate Internal Users
2. Customer Users

The fundamental differences between them technically is

1. Corporate: Don't need to save passwords in the system but only roles (authentication against AD)
2. Customer Users:Save password in the system and have an associated customer ID.

I have a table User which have the columns like so

```
User Name  
Password  
Roles  
Customer ID
```

If I abstract the user creation process using an abstract factory pattern, I get the 2 types of user objects.

Now when it comes to creating a repository, how do I handle it? Do I create 2 different repositories to handle individual user type objects (mapping to same table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can corporate users also be customers?  If so, would you expect them to use the same ID?  If so, you might want to look at implementing the [Party-Role](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29678) pattern (aka Actor-Participant).

It would allow you a unified solution for handling both internal user roles and corporate vs. customer distinction.

hth.

Comment: No. A corporate user is a UserID associated with a Customer so that a Customer can login to the system. There could be multiple user ids associated with a Customer. Customer Profile is a separate record altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider adding a user type column to your user table.  This way you can track what type of user each record represents.  This will be of use when creating user entitys on a find/get operation in your repository layer as well as when you are doing an add or update procedure.  I would suggest only one "user" repository.  You will not need two repository classes if you use inheritance and track the user type at the database level.

Hope this helps.

Enjoy!

Comment: How will the hbm xml look like if we use nHibernate? Since each user type has its own set of fields. We should be having 2 different hbm files one for CorporateUser and one for CustomerUser mapping the corresponding fields to the same table?

Comment: @GeorgeKT - I do not have experience with object realational mappers, and prefer to implement the "repository pattern" directly for performance.  A good description of the repository pattern can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx - Hope this helps

Comment: if a type was introduced, i think a factory would follow suit

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I can give you some hints. I agree with Doug that you should only use one UserRepository that manage User Aggregate classes.

**This is how I would do it with (Fluent) Nhibernate:**

User class with a UserType Enumeration field that is mapped to a single column. See this article, its very good and I've used Jimmy Bogard's solution several times (http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/12/enumeration-classes/). Then you have a UserType class that is actually just represented i database as a column in User table, BUT you have a full class with Behaviour etc.

Then to solve your differences in how each type should handle passwords and Customer relationship, you can use a validator pattern to confirm that your User instance is valid (based on your UserType) before saving it to db. Look at this blog http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2007/10/24/entity-validation-with-visitors-and-extension-methods/ (Jimmy again... Do I need to say that you should subscribe on Jimmy Bogard's blog :)).

Then you have a UserPersistanceValidator that check's if UserType is internal, no pwd is required and AD role must be supplied. You get the picture...

I hope this will help you. Good luck!

Comment: I get the picture. Thank you soooooo much :) @Doug Thanks to you too.